# Some of the Datacenters does not belongs to price location group

Tags: ibm-cloud-infrastructure

I found there are total 30 data-centers among them 16 data-centers have a specific set of price location group ID and 14 data centers are not belongs to any price location group ID (price location group ID = null )

NB : (Using API call I fetched the price location group ID of each and every data-centers).

I want to know that whether those 13 data-centers maintaining the standard pricing mechanism at the time of ordering or not? Why the price location group ID is coming null for those datacenters

Data-centers have some specific price location group ID value :

```
"Sydney 1"
"Melbourne 1"
"Milan 1"
"Hong Kong 2"
"Mexico 1"
"Chennai 1"
"Paris 1"
"Montreal 1"
"London 2"
"Frankfurt 2"
"Singapore 1"
"Amsterdam 1"
"Amsterdam 3"
"Toronto 1"
"Tokyo 2"
"Sao Paulo 1"
```

Data-centers for which price-location group ID = null :

```
"Dallas 7"
"Dallas 5"
"Washington 4"
"Dallas 6"
"Dallas 4"
"Houston 2"
"Washington 1"
"Dallas 1"
"Dallas 2"
"Dallas 10"
"Dallas 9"
"San Jose 1"
"San Jose 3"
"Seattle 1"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See this article it may help you.

http://sldn.softlayer.com/blog/cmporter/location-based-pricing-and-you

Basically the prices are different for datacenters located in other places different from USA. If you see that price-location ID == null that means it is using the standard prices. So the datacenters with price-location ID == null are using the standard prices.

Regards

Comment: Thanks for the help